# Does Wild Onslaught put counters on Hallar, the Firefletcher before or after it's ability triggers

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

If I have a [Hallar, the Firefletcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHallar%2c%20the%20Firefletcher%5d) in play with no +1/+1 counters on it, and I cast [Wild Onslaught](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWild%20Onslaught%5d) and pay it's kicker cost would *Hallar, the Firefletcher* get the two +1/+1 counters from *Wild Onslaught* before or after *Hallar, the Firefletcher's* ability triggers?

Comment: "Hallar’s last ability resolves before the spell that caused it to trigger." from Gatherer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hallar's ability will resolve first, dealing 1 damage.**

Triggers that react to a spell being cast trigger at the end of the spell-casting process. By the time Hallar's ability triggers and goes on the stack, Wild Onslaught is already on the stack and will resolve second.

> 601. Casting Spells
>
> 601.2a **To propose the casting of a spell, a player first moves that card (or that copy of a card) from where it is to the stack.** It becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has all the characteristics of the card (or the copy of a card) associated with it, and that player becomes its controller. The spell remains on the stack until it’s countered, it resolves, or an effect moves it elsewhere.
>
> 601.2i Once the steps described in 601.2a–h are completed, effects that modify the characteristics of the spell as it’s cast are applied, then the spell becomes cast. **Any abilities that trigger when a spell is cast or put onto the stack trigger at this time.** If the spell’s controller had priority before casting it, he or she gets priority.